# Why Express.js' app.get() can only work in the same file app.listen() is called?

Tags: node.js, express

When app.listen() is in the same file as app.get(), it works; and when I add app.get() calls in other files via require, they don't work:

```
// ~ means root folder
// This below is in ~/index.js
var routes = require('~/routes/routes.js');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});

app.get('/snails', function (req, res) {
    res.send('ESCARGOT');
});

// This below is in ~/routes/routes.js
var app = module.exports = require('exports')();

app.get('/birds', function () {
    res.send('PENGUIN');
});

// SUCCESS -> localhost:3000/snails will return "ESCARGOT"
// FAIL -> localhost:3000/birds will return "Cannot GET /birds"
```

Second example to prove the point; this time, app.listen() is moved to routes.js:

```
// ~ means root folder
// The below is in ~/index.js
var routes = require('~/routes/routes.js');

app.get('/snails', function (req, res) {
    res.send('ESCARGOT');
});

// The below is in ~/routes/routes.js
var app = module.exports = require('exports')();

app.get('/birds', function () {
    res.send('PENGUIN');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});

// FAIL -> localhost:3000/snails will return "Cannot GET /snails"
// SUCCESS -> localhost:3000/birds will return "PENGUIN"
```

Why is this so? Is it because app.listen() only targets the file that it is called in?

Comment: Are you including `routes/routes.js`?  Does it have access to `app`?

Comment: Editing the codes above to include them

Comment: I'm not sure why this would work since you don't add `res` as one of the route callback parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your app and include it in your routes file

```
module.exports = app;
```

And then in your routes file

```
var app = include('pathtoyourapp.js');
```

Then you'll have access to your app in your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something along the lines of this in `routes/routes.js`

```
module.exports = function(app) {
   app.get('/birds', function(req, res, next) {
     res.send('Hello');
   });
};
```

and in the index.js

```
var app = express();
app.get('/snails', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('SNAILS');
});
require('./routes/routes')(app);

app.listen(3000);
```

should now work.

BTW i'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do by doing `require('exports')()`, and it looks weird that you are actually exporting that, instead of the `app` (that contains the new `birds` route) in `routes/routes.js`, so that's why it probably doesn't work. Try the way I suggested.

Let me know if you need any additional things.

Answer (score 0):

Use example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('Test message');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(port);
```

Most important is:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port);
```

Send **app** argument for manipulation of servers behaviors.